# Removing multiple XML Nodes, if some other nodes does not contains specific childs

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a complex xml which looks like this one:

```
<rootElement>
    <vElement number="0">
        <!-- Next node, elB, could or could not appear -->
        <elB>SomeData</elB>
        <block>
            <wFormNum>0</wFormNum>
        </block>
    </vElement>
    <vElement number="1">
        <block>
            <wFormNum>1</wFormNum>
        </block>
    </vElement>
    <vElement number="2">
        <!-- Next node, elB, could or could not appear -->
        <elB>SomeData</elB>
        <block>
            <wFormNum>0</wFormNum>
        </block>
    </vElement>
    <vElement number="3">
        <block>
            <wFormNum>2</wFormNum>
        </block>
    </vElement>
    <vElement number="4">
        <block>
            <wFormNum>3</wFormNum>
        </block>
    </vElement>

    .
    .
    .

    <wForm number="0">
    </wForm>
    <wForm number="1">
        <kB number="0"></kB>
        <kB number="1"></kB>
        <kB number="2"></kB>
        <kB number="3"></kB>
    </wForm>
    <wForm number="2">
        <kB number="0"></kB>
        <kB number="1"></kB>
        <kB number="2"></kB>
        <kB number="3"></kB>
        <kB number="4"></kB>
        <kB number="5"></kB>
        <kB number="6"></kB>
        <kB number="7"></kB>
    </wForm>
    <wForm number="3">
    </wForm>
</rootElement>
```

As you see, the element `<vElement>` contains a child element `<block>`, which also has the child `<wFormNum>`. `<wFormNum>`'s value must find in attribute `number` of a `<wForm>` element. So a `<vElement>` is in pair with a `<wForm>` element.

I have to remove some of the `<vElement>` and `<wForm>` elements from this xml, if some conditions are met. The conditions are the following:

- If element `<vElement>` contains child element `<elB>` this one will **not** be deleted. The `<wForm>` element which is in pair, also, will not be deleted.
- If element `<vElement>` does not contains child element `<elB>` and `<wForm>`'s does not contains childs `<kB>` it **will be** deleted.
- If element `<vElement>` does not contains child element `<elB>` but paired `<wForm>` contains childs `<kB>` it will **NOT** be deleted.
- A `<wForm>` element could be in pair with multiple `<vElement>`.

So to be more clearly, I will give you from the above example of xml code, which elements will must be deleted:

- Element `<vElement number="0">` must NOT be deleted, because it contains the child element `<elB></elB>`. Also the element `<wForm number="0">` will not be deleted, because is in pair with this `<vElement number="0">`, set by `<wFormNum>0</wformNum>`.
- Element `<vElement number="1">` could be deleted, because not contains the child element `<elB></elB>`, BUT is in pair with `<wForm number="1">`, set by `<wFormNum>1</wformNum>`, and that `<wForm number="1">` contains elements of type `<kB>`. So `<vElement number="1">` and `<wForm number="1">` will NOT be deleted.
- Element `<vElement number="2">` is the same as `<vElement number="0">`, so will NOT be deleted.
- Element `<vElement number="3">` is the same as `<vElement number="1">`, so it will not be deleted, and also, `<wForm number="2">` will not be deleted.
- Element `<vElement number="4">` it will be deleted because does not contains any `<elB></elB>` child elements, and also, `<wForm number="3">` does not contains `<kB></kB>` child elements. `<wForm number="3">` will be also deleted, because does not contains `<kB>` childs and is not in pair with other `<vElement>` which cannot be deleted.

I want to remove "removable" nodes (`<vElement>` and `<wForm>`) from a single line of code if it is possible, using Linq. I tried with multiple `foreach()` instructions, but is complicated, because of those "containing or not containing child elements" thing :(

Thanks.

Comment: On third test does both vElement and vForm not get deleted?  I may delete the wForm.  You said "it" which is not very specific.

Comment: I don't know what test do you refer to?

Comment: I just update Answer with differences.

Comment: In my example, the only pair that can be deleted is vElement number 4 and wform number 3. wform number 1 and number 2 cannot be deleted, because contains kB elements. wform number 0 cannot be deleted because is paired with vElement 0 and vElement 2 and both vElement contains elB elements. You understand?

Comment: I updated code so now wForm = 1 does not get deleted.  wForm = 3 has no kB so it gets deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203996/discussion-between-vali-maties-and-jdweng).

Comment: I think it is correct now.

Comment: I'm bothered by your logic.  I've done lots of logic issue like this before.  Usually when you look at final results you can figure out why each node was kept.  In your case I look at vElement = 3 and cannot determine why it was kept.  There is no link to a wForm and no elB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't vote this as the answer, because is different that what I try to found out, a LINQ version, with a short and nice visible code, but this is what I get to do and to work, and respects the statement:

```
private static void RemoveEmptyWForms(string filePath, string vN, string rPN) {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        List<wForm> listWForms = new List<wForm>();
        List<Elements> listElements = new List<Elements>();
        if (xml.Descendants("vElement").Count() == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not contains elements of type \"vElement\"!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (XElement xe in xml.Descendants("vElement"))
            {
                Elements el = new Elements();
                el.PNV = rPN + " | " + vN;
                el.Node = xe;
                el.Value = xe.Attribute("number").Value;
                listElements.Add(el);
            }
        }
        foreach (XElement xw in xml.Descendants("wForm"))
        {
            string value = xw.Attribute("number").Value;
            wForm wfn = new wForm();
            wfn.PNV = rPN + " | " + vN;
            wfn.Node = xw;
            wfn.Value = value;
            if (xw.Descendants("kB").Count() > 0)
            {
                wfn.CanBeDeleted = false;
                listWForms.Add(wfn);
                continue;
            }
            wfn.CanBeDeleted = true;
            listWForms.Add(wfn);
            foreach (XElement xe in xml.Descendants("vElement")) {
                if (xe.Descendants("elB").Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Elements el in listElements)
                    {
                        if (el.Node != xe) continue;
                        else { 
                            el.CanBeDeleted = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    string xeWfn = xe.Element("block").Element("wFormNum").Value;
                    foreach (wForm wf in listWForms) {
                        if (wf.Value.Equals(xeWfn))
                        {
                            if (wf.CanBeDeleted == false) 
                            {
                                foreach (Elements el in listElements)
                                {
                                    if (el.Node != xe) continue;
                                    else
                                    {
                                        el.CanBeDeleted = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            foreach (Elements el in listElements)
                            {
                                if (el.Node != xe) continue;
                                else
                                {
                                    el.CanBeDeleted = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (wForm wf in listWForms) {
            if (wf.CanBeDeleted) { 
                wf.Node.Remove();
                Console.WriteLine("Removing wForm {0} from v {1}", wf.Value, wf.PNV);
            }
        }
        foreach (Elements el in listElements) {
            if (el.CanBeDeleted) { 
                el.Node.Remove();
                Console.WriteLine("Removing element {0} from v {1}", el.Value, el.PNV);
            }
        }
    }

class WaveForm { 
    public string PNV { get; set; }
    public XNode Node { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool CanBeDeleted { get; set; } = true;
}
class Elements {
    public string PNV{ get; set; }
    public XNode Node { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool CanBeDeleted { get; set; } = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.  I updated code.  vElement does not contian elb so your comments are wrong about vElement 1 and wForm 1 not getting deleted. Following gets deleted : (1) vElement 3 & 4 (2) wForm 3.  I'm using xml linq.

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<WForm> wforms = doc.Descendants("wForm")
                .Select(x => new WForm() { number = (int)x.Attribute("number"), element = x })
                .ToList();

            var results = (from vElement in doc.Descendants("vElement")
                           join wForm in wforms on (int)vElement.Attribute("number") equals wForm.number into v
                           from wForm in v.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { vElement = vElement, wForm = wForm }
                          ).ToList();

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                if (result.vElement.Element("elB") != null)
                {
                    if (result.wForm != null) result.wForm.delete = false;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (result.wForm != null)
                    {
                        if (result.wForm.element.Element("kB") != null)
                        {
                            result.wForm.delete = false;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int number = (int)result.vElement.Attribute("number");
                        Console.WriteLine("Remove vElement : '{0}'", number);
                        result.vElement.Remove();
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (WForm wForm in wforms)
            {
                if (wForm.delete)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Remove wForm : '{0}'", wForm.number);
                    wForm.element.Remove();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class WForm
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public bool delete = true;
        public XElement element { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your rules as I understand it is to remove `<vElement>` nodes where the following are true:

1. `<vElement>` does not contain any `<elB>` child nodes.
2. `<vElement>` does not have a corresponding `<wForm>` element that is not empty.

```
XElement Cleanup(XElement element)
{
    var clean = new XElement(element);
    var nonEmptyForms = clean.XPathSelectElements("//wForm[*]")
        .Select(f => (int)f.Attribute("number"))
        .ToHashSet();
    clean.XPathSelectElements("//vElement")
        .Where(e => !e.Elements("elB").Any())
        .Where(e => !nonEmptyForms.Contains((int)e.XPathSelectElement("block/wFormNum")))
        .Remove();
    return clean;
}
```

Comment: No Jeff, it is not about Empty. I think I wrote very clear, that those elements MUST contains those child elements, with those names, `<elB>` for `<vElement>` and `<kB>` for `<wForm>`. In the same time, `<wForm>` cannot be deleted, even if does not contains `<kB>` childs, but it is paired with a `<vElement>` thru `<block><wFormNum>` child of `<vElement>`.
This structure which I post here is a light structure of a much much branchy xml file.